Hide Customer IP address in WooCommerce admin edit order pages
I tried my best googling on how to hide the customer IP address shown in the WooCommerce order edit pages, but no code has helped me yet.

I basically just want to show the Payment method to the shop manager(i.e. : via Card Payment). I want to get rid of any other text.
This question WooCommerce - Change paid text in admin panel order details page gave me some understanding on how to remove the Paid on text (ps : I replaced it with "").
But other than this, I got no clue how to hide the Customer IP address.
I tried the following code, without success:
add_filter( 'update_post_metadata', 'mp1401091554', 10, 3 );

function mp1401091554( $null, $id, $key ) {
    if ( '_customer_ip_address' === $key )
        return FALSE;

    return $null;
}


You could use some CSS to hide the customer IP address, like:
add_action( 'admin_head', 'admin_edit_order_css' );
function admin_edit_order_css() {
    global $pagenow, $typenow;

    if ( ( $pagenow === 'post.php' && $typenow === 'shop_order' && isset($_GET['post']) ) 
    || ( $pagenow === 'admin.php' && isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] === 'wc-orders'
    && isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] === 'edit' && isset($_GET['id']) ) ) : ?>
    <style> .woocommerce-Order-customerIP {display:none;} </style>
    <?php endif;
}

But it will only hide the IP address itself, but not "Customer IP:" substring.
So you can use instead Javascript to remove the IP and hide "Customer IP:" substring like:
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'admin_edit_order_script' );
function admin_edit_order_script() {
    global $pagenow, $typenow;

    if ( ( $pagenow === 'post.php' && $typenow === 'shop_order' && isset($_GET['post']) ) 
    || ( $pagenow === 'admin.php' && isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] === 'wc-orders'
    && isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] === 'edit' && isset($_GET['id']) ) ) : ?>
    <script>
    jQuery('.woocommerce-Order-customerIP').remove();
    const orderNumberMeta = jQuery('.woocommerce-order-data__meta.order_number'), 
    orderNumberMetaHTML = orderNumberMeta.html();
    orderNumberMeta.html(orderNumberMetaHTML.replace('Customer IP:', ''));
    </script>
    <?php endif;
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works with or without HPOS enabled.
You will get something like:


Thanks ! This works like a charm. There's only one tiny issue , when I remove both the Customer IP and Paid on text I am left with  Payment via cash/card. But the via card has some extra " . " after the full stop. Which is kinda annoying. Should I create a different question for it?

@MohammedMalleck The rule is one question at the time, so Yes you should create a new question (providing your own code attempt) as I don't really understand what you are talking about.

done!(apologies I am new here).
